# How to place DIVs from left to right AND take width from first item only?

Tags: css, html, menu

I want to style DIVs in the following way for menu:

[image]

Where red is menu bar, cyan is drop down menu and green is menu's head. Menu head can be shorter than rest menu items, so only menu head should be taken into account while laying out menus.

Is this possible to accomplish?

My test is here: http://jsfiddle.net/suzancioc/W2W45/2/

```
<div class='menubar'>
<div class='menu'>
   <div class='menuhead'>menu 1</div>
   <div class='menubody'>
       long item name 1.1</br>
       long item name 1.2</br>
       long item name 1.3</br>          
   </div>
</div>
<div class='menu'>
   <div class='menuhead'>menu 2</div>
   <div class='menubody'>
       long item name 2.1</br>
       long item name 2.2</br>
       long item name 2.3</br>          
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.menubar {
   /*some fancy css*/
   height:20px;
   background:red;
}
.menu {
   float:left;
   margin:1px;
   background: cyan;
}
.menuhead {
    background: green;
}
```

As you see, menu width is appeared to be calculated on all rows lengths, not only head ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your intention correctly, you need to use absoulute positioning for that, by adding `.menubody{position:absolute;}` rule. I have forked your jsfiddle and applied it, hover  `.menuhead`s to see `.menubody`s. Url is here: http://jsfiddle.net/goktugkayaalp/3usYQ/